# Django Grappelli Rearrange Inlines id override

Tags: django, django-grappelli

According to the docs:

http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization.html#rearrange-inlines

> The two classes for the placeholder are important. First, you need a class placeholder. The second class has to match the id of the inline–group.

All's well and good, I was able to set up my inlines fine, my issue is now - where does grappelli get the "id of the inline group"  I can't find any reference, and pouring through the source code is offering me no solace.

Simply, I want to change the element-id that grappelli is using.  Currently, it looks to me that it is taking the object name itself and converting to a lowercase name and appending set to the end.  Do we have access to override the "id of the inline-group"?

Also, I am not 100% sure exactly how (or where) grappelli is doing this, it is definitely not documented...  at all in fact.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the id of the inline element on HTML page. You can check the id of the default HTML inline element.

```
 <div id="[related_name of ForeignKey]-group">
```

For example:
If in model "MyModel2", you have a ForeignKey like this:

```
my_model_1 = models.ForeignKey(MyModel1, related_name='my_model_2')
```

Then the id should be "my_model_2-group".

Answer (score 0):

The id of the inline group is set in [grappelli/templates/admin/edit_inline](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli/tree/master/grappelli/templates/admin/edit_inline), in stacked.html line 5, or tabular.html line 6 (depending on which type of inline you're usng):

```
id="{{ inline_admin_formset.formset.prefix }}-group" >
```

You can override this by copying the file (stacked.html or tabular.html) into your template directory and setting the variable "template" to the file's new location e.g.:

```
# admin.py

class MyModelInline(admin.StackedInline):
    template = 'path/to/stacked.html'
    ...
```

Then edit whatever you want in e.g. stacked.html.

I don't know if this is the best-practices way of doing this, but it's similar to what's done in the django tutorial.